# Multiplying by another variable in inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a > 3$ and $b > 5$

What type of operations can I do?

Can I do $a * a > 9$ or       $a * b > 15$ or at least if I can't do that then can I know the sign like $a > 5$ and $b > 3$ then $a*b > 0$ ?

Comment: $a \cdot a > 9$ and $a \cdot b > 15$ are perfectly reasonable conclusions for $a > 3$ and $b > 5$.

Comment: Yes, For positive values, $a > c$ and $b > d$ imply $ab > cd$. You can figure out similar rules when some of the values are negative. You should experiment with many examples to become comfortable with these kinds of implications. (Some day you may be in a position to prove them.)

Comment: Thanks someone told me that you can do any operation except dividing and subtracting is that True?

Answer (score 1):

You can do all operations in this way, as long as you are not dividing by 0.

**For addition**  (note $\land$ means "and"):
$$\text{given } a>b, c>d, \text{then } a+c>b+d$$
$$\text{because } a>b \implies a+c>b+c, \text{while } c>d \implies b+c>b+d$$
$$\text{therefore } \{\{a+c>b+c\} \land \{b+c>b+d\}\} \implies a+c>b+c>b+d \implies a+c>b+d$$
**For subtraction** the process is exactly the same. You can imagine every "+" here to turn into  "-", or think of it as adding a negative number.

**For multiplication** with *positive* numbers:
$$\text{given } a>b, c>d, \text{then } ac>bd$$
$$\text{because } a>b \implies ac>bc, \text{while } c>d \implies bc>bd$$
$$\text{therefore } \{ac>bc \land bc>bd\} \implies ac>bc>bd \implies ac>bd$$
**For multiplication** with *negative* numbers:
$$\text{you should just keep note that multiplying by a negative number reverses the inequality sign,}$$
$$\text{so for } -c<0 \implies c>0,$$
$$a>b\implies 0<bc<ac \implies -ac<-bc<0$$
$$\text{because} -ac<-bc<0<bc<ac$$
$$\text{so } a>b \implies -ac<-bc$$
$$\text{you can think of it as a reflection across 0 on the numberline}$$
**For division** you can think of it as multiplying fractions, so everything will work as long as the denmonator of this fraction is not 0. Also note that you cannot multiply inequalities by 0. For example, let's say you could, then $a<b\implies 0a<0b \implies 0<0 \implies 0\neq 0$, which is absurd.

I have covered all the operations. Hope this helped.